# How can I mute WatiN IE browser sound?

Tags: c#, watin

I am using WatiN IE browser in my program. How can I mute the IE page navigation sounds when its running in invisible mode?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this configuration is at the system level, and not configurable at the control level.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the accessibility setting "play system sounds" in the advanced options list in IE

or change your sound settings in control panel to not make the sound for "start navigation"?

I hope you are only ever running IE in invisible mode using WatiN what would the neighbours think if they saw you browsing on it let alone hear you browsing on it :-)

Comment: It looks so awesome to have browser window navigating themselves though!  :)